# How I can set up dependencies for two interfaces?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Have a table component, which has a param with an array of rows data. It described with interface:

```
interface ITableProps {
    columns: Array<IHeadCell>;  
    model: Array<IRowData>;
    getRowId?: (row: IRowData) => string | number;
    striped?: boolean;
    useCheckbox?: boolean;
}
```

where `model` is an array of rows. Single row described by next interface:

```
interface IRowData {
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

How I can make a type checking for these two interfaces, with the next scenario:
if table property `useCheckbox` has a true value, interface `IRowData` has the required property `selected`. And if table property `useCheckbox` has a false value or is not defined, `IRowData` did not require `selected` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While what you require isn't possible, you can work around that using a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) and the [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility type.

If in place of `ITableProps` you have:

```
interface ITableProps {
    columns: Array<IHeadCell>;  
    model: Array<IRowData>;
    getRowId?: (row: IRowData) => string | number;
    striped?: boolean;
    useCheckbox?: false;
}

interface ICheckboxTableProps extends Omit<ITableProps, "useCheckbox"> {
    model: Array<IRowData & { selected: boolean }>;
    useCheckbox: true;
}

type TableProps = ICheckboxTableProps | ITableProps;
```

then `ICheckboxTableProps` extends `ITableProps` except for the `useCheckBox` property, which is replaced with `true`.

Therefore, with the union type created as `TableProps`, it will use:

- the interface `ITableProps` if `useCheckbox` is false or undefined, and
- the interface `ICheckboxTableProps` which requires `IRowData.selected` if it's true.

Thus:

```
const table: TableProps = {
    // ...
    model: [],
    useCheckbox: false
}
```

is valid.

So is

```
const checkedTable: TableProps = {
    // ...
    model: [{ selected: true }],
    useCheckbox: true
}
```

But

```
const invalidTable: TableProps = {
     model: [{ otherProp: "otherValue" }],
     useCheckbox: true
}
```

is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using union type on the `ITableProps`.

```js
type ITableProps = {
    columns: Array<IHeadCell>;  
    model: Array<IHaveCheckboxRowData>;
    getRowId?: (row: IHaveCheckboxRowData) => string | number;
    striped?: boolean;
    useCheckbox: true;
} | {
    columns: Array<IHeadCell>;  
    model: Array<INoCheckboxRowData>;
    getRowId?: (row: INoCheckboxRowData) => string | number;
    striped?: boolean;
    useCheckbox?: false;
}

interface IHaveCheckboxRowData {
    selected: boolean;
    [key: string]: any;
}

interface INoCheckboxRowData {
    selected?: boolean;
    [key: string]: any;
}
```